# Install on flash drive: scaring message on "LVM VG fedora, LV swap as swap" being formatted

Tags: system-installation, lvm, fedora

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a USB flash drive, attached to a Fedora 33 machine.
I am following [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/install_an_entire_ubuntu_on_a_usb_flash_drive/).
Up to [this screenshot](https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/word-image-1184.png) everything seems to be fine but I get a message as below:

```
If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually.

WARNING: This will destroy all data on any partitions you have removed as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.

The partition tables of the following devices are changed:
 SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdc)

The following partitions are going to be formatted:
 LVM VG fedora, LV swap as swap    <<<<<<?????
 partition #1 of SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdc) as ext4
 partition #5 of SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdc) as ext4
 partition #6 of SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdc) as swap
```

Question: why is `LVM VG_ Fedora listed`? why  `LV swap as swap`? If I proceed, is there any risk I mess up with Fedora?
Thanks

EDIT: added screenshots of the installation procedure:

[Disks seen by Live Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MILYz.png)

[Normal/Minimal installation --> I chose Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R060J.png)

[Installation type --> I chose "Something else" and no other options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsDZ9.png)

[Partitions creation --> I created three partition for /, /home and swap area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5o99.png)

[The warning message (that I copied also above in the post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnPj.png)

As you can see, I'd like to install Ubuntu 18.04 on the 64GB USB flash drive `/dev/sdc`, which I tried to divide in three partitions using the Ubuntu installer tool (fourth screenshot).
While Fedora 33 is on another hard disk, `/dev/sda`, which is my laptop hard disk as you can see in the first screenshot.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain how you’re installing Ubuntu on your Fedora machine? This will make it more likely that someone can offer a complete answer to your question 

Comment: Are you intending to create a Logical Volume? Or an encrypted volume? Alternately, did you want a plain, unencrypted ext4 volume instead? These are options you were presented with -- looks like you chose the defaults.

Comment: @matigo I edited the question. Is it better?

Comment: @user535733 I am not sure, I don't want to erase my disk, I'm trying to install on a fresh usb flash drive. Yes I want to have a plain unencrypted ext4 volume (option "Something else"). How is that I have that message about LVM Fedora?

Comment: @user535733 I've added some screenshots of what I did in the installation procedure.

Comment: @user535733 I do not think he has already completed the install. Most likely, he is trying [Try Ubuntu without installing](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#3-boot-from-usb-flash-drive). The question is not moot, since I would not expect to see a msg about  `LV swap as swap` being formatted too. Unfortunately, I can't help, I do not know whether that is harmless.

Comment: Your "Disks seen by Live Ubuntu" image suggests that you have an LVM (perhaps encrypted, too) Fedora install. Your installer output indicates that the installer is offering to overwrite (destroy) that Fedora install. Since that does not seem to be what you want, I suggest installing to a different device or partition instead.

Comment: @user535733 in the end I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a usb flash drive by doing exactly what I posted in the screenshots and I was able to remove the message about the Fedora by setting to "do not use partition" the Fedora swap partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to select the **Fedora swap partition** from the Ubuntu 18.04 installer (in the **Partitions creation** step) and change it from "swap area" to "do not use this partition".

The error message disappeared and I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB flash drive and dual boot either on it or on Fedora 33.